# How to make a dice roll UPDATE table data based on the roll result in php

Tags: php, mysqli

i have a problem figuring out, how to roll the dice/s, so that the result/s will either do nothing or only UPDATE the selected users inventory.

```
<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
    {
        include 'system/config.php';
        //SESSION
        $username = $_SESSION['loggedin'];

        //selecting id from table users                         
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username ='$username'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        //the user id from users
        $user_id      = $row['id'];

        $sql = "SELECT user_id, size_kg, fish1, fish2, fish3, fish4, fish5, seaweed FROM inventory WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        $userId= $row['user_id'];
        $fish1 = $row['fish1'];
        $fish2 = $row['fish2'];
        $fish3 = $row['fish3'];
        $fish4 = $row['fish4'];
        $fish5 = $row['fish5'];
        $seaweed = $row['seaweed'];

        //for debug
        echo "$userId. id " . "$fish1 . fish1 <br>";


        //$CatchProbability: dice roll for Catch Probability (ex: CatchProbability >= 30; echo You cought a $FishType(fish1, fish2, fish3, fish4, fish5, seaweed))
        function rollcatch() {
        return mt_rand(1,100);
        }
        echo rollcatch()." catch <br>";//for debug


        //$FishType: dice roll for type of Fish (ex: $FishType(fish1) = 1-10 , $FishType(fish2) = 11-20, $FishType(fish4) = 31-40 $FishType(fish5) = 41-50, $FishType(seaweed) = 51-100)
        function rolltype() {
        return mt_rand(1,100);
        } 
        echo rolltype()." type <br>";//for debug


        function catchFish(){
            if(rollcatch() < 30){
                $rolltype = rolltype();
                $result = "";
                if($rolltype > 0 && $rolltype<10){
                    $result = "fish1";
                }
                else if($rolltype > 10 && $rolltype<=20){
                    $result = "fish2";
                }
                else if($rolltype > 20 && $rolltype<=30){
                    $result = "fish3";
                }
                else if($rolltype > 30 && $rolltype<=40){
                    $result = "fish4";
                }
                else if($rolltype > 40 && $rolltype<=50){
                    $result = "fish5";
                }
                else
                {
                $result="seaweed";
                }
                $sql = "UPDATE inventory SET $result = $result + 1 WHERE user_id='$userId'";
                if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
                    echo("You caught a $result");
                }      

            }
            else
            {
                echo("You caught nothing...");
            }
        }
            catchFish(); //for debug
    }

?>
```

Please, help me to debug, I get this error on successful catch:
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in ... on line 72

Line 72

```
<?  
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
        echo("You caught a $result");
    }     
?>
```

Comment: There are several problems with your code. One for example being the fact that you're open to SQL Injection. Another one would be lack of information. How is the probability supposed to work? If it's say 30%, does that mean 30% chance on a fish and 70% chance on seaweed?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am still Very low level in learning the php code. Where and how am i open to SQL Injection. Yes, 30% chance of cathing fish and 70% is seaweed.

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username ='$username'";` That's where you're open to SQL injection (and all the other queries). NEVER EVER include variables directly into your queries. Always use a placeholder and [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Thank you, i will look into it. id like to clarify the the dice rolling aswell.
In catchProbability the 30% is the chance of cathing anything.

Comment: I see now what you asked.
In catchProbability the 30% is the chance of cathing anything.
In fishType the results 1-50 is the chance of cathing certain type of fish. and with result 51-100 is the chance of cathing only seaweed.

Comment: You see, this site is not intended "to make your code work". You cannot demand such a result here. After all, it is you are a programmer and it is *your* job to make it work

Comment: Thank you Your Common Sense, i cant agree more, i want more than anything to finish this thing by myself. The issue here is that i am low level on any of the coding languages. If i can see the correct way it should be done so it works, i have better understanding on how it works and why. This piece of code is not finished by a long shot. its just a piece of it i have a problem with.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly:

```
if($CatchProbability <= 30) {
    $FishType = rolltype();
    if ($FishType <= 10) {
        $sql = "UPDATE inventory SET fish1 = fish1 +1 WHERE user_id = '$userId'";
        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
        { 
            echo " </br> You caught one Fish1.</br>";
        }
    }
    echo 'You caught a '.$FishType.';
```

Comment: You're in the right direction, but as of right now, OP simply didn't provide enough information to answer this question correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure I understood perfectly, but this code:

1. Checks if you caught a fish (30% chance)
2. Determines which fish you caught (10% chance for fish 1-5, 50% chance seaweed)
3. Adds 1 to the caught fish in the database
4. Outputs a message of which fish you caught

Hopefully this works for you

```
function catchFish(){
    if(rollcatch() < 30){
        $rolltype = rolltype();
        $result = "";
        if($rolltype > 0 && $rolltype<=10){
            $result = "fish1";
        }
        else if($rolltype > 10 && $rolltype<=20){
            $result = "fish2";
        }
        else if($rolltype > 20 && $rolltype<=30){
            $result = "fish3";
        }
        else if($rolltype > 30 && $rolltype<=40){
            $result="fish4";
        }
        else if($rolltype > 40 && $rolltype<=50){
            $result="fish5";
        }
        else
        {
        $result="seaweed";
        }

        $sql = "UPDATE inventory SET $result = $result + 1 WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
        if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
            echo("You caught a $result.");
        }      

    }
    else
    {
        echo("You caught nothing...");
    }
}
```

Comment: with this i get an error: 
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in ... on line 72 ( it being: if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
            echo("You caught a $result.");
        }  )